# Checkbox always returning null in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

i am building a contact form and have a checkbox that looks like this:

```
<input type="Checkbox" name="infomaterial" value="test">send info material<br>
```

i am then using request.getParameter like this:

```
request.getParameter("infomaterial")
```

this is working fine with textboxes and textfields, but it is not working with checkboxes.

I always get null, no matter it is checked or not (i expect it being null when not checked?).. The checkbox is in the right position, too. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="Checkbox" class="msgChk" name="infomaterial" value="test">send info material<br>

var checked = null;
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('msgChk');

for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i)  {       
    if(inputElements[i].checked)  {              
        checked = inputElements[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getParameterValues` to get array of selected checkboxes:

Servlet:

```
String[] infomaterials= request.getParameterValues("infomaterial");
for (String infomaterial:infomaterials) {
   System.out.println(infomaterial); 
}
```

**Also note**, you will only get values for those checkboxes which are selected. If a checkbox is not selected, it's value will not be available in `getParameterValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
I found the problem. I have an "owasp SecurityWrapper" in my program. Somehow, this blocks everything except textfields and textboxes. If i turn it off, it works like expected. Still have to find out why it blocks those Checkboxes..

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but please try

```
boolean infomaterialIsChecked= Boolean.parseBoolean( request.getParameter("infomaterial") );
```

or

```
boolean infomaterialIsChecked= request.getParameter("infomaterial") != null;
```

The Second Option is better. It worked for me